# BizTalk BlobStorageAdapter - Promote Blob Metadata as BizTalk properties

Tags: azure-blob-storage, biztalk, biztalk-2020

I'm using the AzureBlobStorage adapter in BizTalk 2020 and to receive blobs from Azure Blob Storage. The blobs have metadata which I want to use within my orchestration. So I created and deployed a schema containing the metadata keys as elements.

Within the receive location I entered the "Namespace for blob metadata" with the namespace of my schema and checked the checkbox "Promote metadata properties"

Unfortunately I'm getting the following error: "Loading property information by list by namespace failed or property not found in the list. Verify that the schema is deployed properly."

Schema:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<xs:schema xmlns="http://POC.Test.AzBlobMetadata.AzLaParameters" xmlns:b="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003" targetNamespace="http://POC.Test.AzBlobMetadata.AzLaParameters" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:annotation>
    <xs:appinfo>
      <b:schemaInfo schema_type="AzLaParameters" xmlns:b="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003" />
    </xs:appinfo>
  </xs:annotation>
  <xs:element name="MetaData">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="la_name" type="xs:string" />
        <xs:element name="la_runid" type="xs:string" />
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Receive Location / Adapter configuration:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have hopefully solved the issue in the 2 1/4 years since asking? For anyone else in the sorry lonesome state of being that is BizTalk Development, here goes:

First, you have created a *Message* Schema, which will not work. You'll need to create a *Property* Schema, with one field per metadata key assigned to the blob objects. Each field should have "Property Schema Base" set to type "MessageContextPropertyBase", if the purpose of the schema is Promotable properties for message routing. Give the Schema a good Target Namespace and a local namespace. Now deploy the schema to a common resource application.

An example:
[property schema example with target and local namespace, and properties for metadata with lower case naming](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IQocb.png)

On the AzureBlobStorage Receive Location, enter the Target Namespace as the namespace for Blob metadata. On subscribing send ports, you will see the Property Schema's local namespace in the dropdown for filters.

But the real Gotcha here for me was that Property Schema fields must match case exactly with the properties set on the blob metadata by whatever function that wrote it there. So to get it right first time you should check the code for exact casing and spelling and make sure also to add ALL metadata keys that the blobs may have. If you choose Promote Properties, ALL will be attempted but ONE missing - or unmatched by case - will be enough to get the error. Which also means that you need to make sure the developer on the Azure side does not add metadata willy nilly.

If you still get the error you may try to remove the "Promote" option (keep the namespace) and suspend the received message in flight, since all metadata will be in Context Props, just not promoted. But please note that the Context Properties displayed under the suspended message will NOT show the casing accurately, all metadata properties will be shown with Capitalized first letter! This is misleading, indeed.